# How to return an object using jQuery, not only the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm looking for a way of replacing `.val();` in jQuery with something like `.array` or `.object`.  So instead of getting only the value of a drop down, i can return the full array for the selected value.

I have a drop down which allows a user to select multiple 'gameTypes', i'm outputting this to the screen and when the user clicks next the content of these 'gameTypes' should be sent as a JSON request.

The code i'm currently using is below however it only returns the 'gametype' name, so when i run the code i get 'RPG' in the console.  What i need is the full object, so RPG, publishers, games etc.

Ive looked at the API documentation in jQuery and can't find a way of doing it, is it possible with jQuery?

Js Code:

```
$("#nextbutton").click(function () {
         var datatosend = {
             gametypes: [],
             market: [] //This is populated using the same method however i don't need the whole object, just the name so this works
         };
             $("#comboGameType").find(":selected").each(function() {
             var str = $(this).val();
             datatosend.gametypes.push(str);
             console.log(str);
         });

});
```

JSON example:

```
{
"games": [{
    "gameType": "RPG",
    "publishers": [{
        "publisher": "Square",
        "titles": [{
            "title": "Final Fantasy",
            "gameReleases": [ 2006, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2014 ]
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

The html is pretty standard, it's populated through js

```
<select id="comboGameType" class="selectpicker" multiple> </select>
```

JS to handle changes to drop down and display selections:

```
$('#comboGameType').change(function () {
     var values = $('#comboGameType').val();
     var parsedData = JSON.parse($myData);
     for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
         $('#output').append("<div>" + values[i] + "</div>")
     }
 });
```

Heres a fiddle to show as an example - when you view console see the value of the drop down is returned, however i'm trying to return the FULL object (so everything in RPG for example)  http://jsfiddle.net/2Ma7U/

Comment: So, what HTML are you working with?

Comment: I think you must build the JSON array by yourself

Comment: Added the HTML and js to handle the output

Comment: please provide jsFiddle for the same

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2Ma7U/

Comment: Provided a fiddle above - i can get the effect i want by hard coding an index value:
`var getGenre = parsedData.gameType[0];`

However it's worthless because it only brings back the first gametype object, and if i put it in a loop it brings back more, but in the order of the JSON, not bound to the selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store the entire object and retrieve it later.

```
$(parsedData.genres).each(function (i) {
     $("#pubCombo").append($("<option/>", {
         val: this.genre,
         html: this.genre,
         data: this
     }));
 });


$("#next").click(function () {
         var datatosend = {
             gametypes: [],
             market: []
         };
             $("#pubCombo").find(":selected").each(function() {
             var obj = $(this).data();
             datatosend.gametypes.push(obj);
             console.log(obj);
         });

});
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2Ma7U/1/

Comment: Thats great, many thanks Nemoy, looked everywhere for something to replace .val(), just didn't see data.  Cheers!